# can't http from android browser to ubuntu http service over wifi

Tags: android, http, ubuntu, networking, lan

I have a apache server running on my Ubuntu laptop which is connected to wifi and over the same wifi network, i have my andorid phone connected.

When i try to connect to apache web server home page from android browser, it gives host unreachable. also when i try to ping using terminal emulator on android, it gives same message, "Host unreachable".

i check firewall on android, it has http/80 port open.

the wireless router i am using is Netgear JNR1010.

What could be the issue as it ideally should be able to connect?

**EDIT:** including more details

**Ubuntu ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5asdw:5sdf5:sfe4:asfd:afq3:adfsdf  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6456404 (6.4 MB)  TX bytes:6456404 (6.4 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr asf15:sfsd:551511:zf:5s5d:4sDF  
          inet addr:10.0.0.13  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: zxc::zxc:zxc:zxc:zxc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1537732 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:391968 (391.9 KB)
```

**Android ifconfig**

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:53938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4568288 (4.3 MiB)  TX bytes:4568288 (4.3 MiB)

p2p0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr asd:sdf:sdfsd:afs:afsdf:sdfe1
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4df:sdfsd:asfas:asfA:asfq2:asf2
          inet addr:10.0.0.9  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:300872 errors:0 dropped:344 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:186978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:232591035 (221.8 MiB)  TX bytes:25023755 (23.8 MiB)
```

**netstat -anp|grep :80** - Ubuntu

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.13:55288         445.889.322.651:80        ESTABLISHED 2959/chrome     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.13:37328         15.231.1511.2115:80       ESTABLISHED 2959/chrome     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers**: Ubuntu

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 108 packets, 3576 bytes)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    24411   13M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2    24411   13M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3      284 18450 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4      108  3576 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5      108  3576 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    6      108  3576 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1        0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2        0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3        0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4        0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5        0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    6        0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 80 bytes)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    24346   11M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2    24346   11M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3      721 82037 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4      721 82037 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5      721 82037 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    6      721 82037 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1       43  3894 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    2       25  5868 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    3        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    4        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    5        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    6        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    7      108  5112 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

    Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

    Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1       92  3056 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

    Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    7        0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    17215 9965K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2     6855 2658K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
4        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
10       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
11     341 24125 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
12      57  5675 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
13       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
14     284 18450 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    17215 9965K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2     6410  542K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3      721 82037 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2      165  9251 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
3      176 14874 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
4        0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      176 14874 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      145  8700 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
2      574 73257 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
2        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
3        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
2        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**ping -c 4 ubuntu** #ping from android to ubuntu

```
ping -c 4 10.0.0.13
PING 10.0.0.13 (10.0.0.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.0.0.13 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3006ms
pipe 3
```

**EDIT 2:**

my default gateway (router) is 10.0.0.1 so ping to it gives  100% packet loss from ubuntu laptop, same from android

Comment: Are you able to ping the gateway (the router)?

Comment: @cricket_007 `ping 192.168.1.1` gives host unreachable

Comment: @cricket_007 my default gateway (router) is 10.0.0.1 so ping to it gives  100% packet loss from ubuntu laptop, same from android

Comment: dohhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!! had my "wireless isolation" on. sh@#!#$@ silly. got it working now.

Comment: Networking debugging 101 - Make sure you can access the intermediate points :)

Answer (score 0):

Show your ifconfig output from Ubuntu Server and Android.

```
ifconfig #both devices
netstat -anp|grep :80 #Ubuntu
iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers #Ubuntu
ping -c 4 ubuntu #ping from android to ubuntu
```

Comment: check edit. i have edited some ip  and h/w addresses with randoms

Answer (score 0):

Had my "wireless isolation" **on**. Turned it off from router. got it working now.